# How Can I insert a text box by using the Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

Am new for the ASPX, I have a problem in developing the code. Please see below. How Can i set a text box beside to delete button?

```
testTypeNode.Text = testTypeNode.Text & "" & _
                    " <img src=""../images/delete_16x.ico""" & _
                    " style=""text-align:bottom; cursor:pointer;"" alt=""Delete TestType""" & _
                    " title=""Delete TestType"" onclick=""javascript:if(confirm('`enter code here`Are you sure you want to delete? Any running tests will be aborted!'))" & _
                    " {" & ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnDeleteTestType, "" & sequenceNode.Value.ToString & _
                    WordSeparationChar & testTypeNode.Value.ToString & "") & ";};"" />"
```

Comment: You want this to happen with a post-back to server, or on the client-side?

Comment: Are you just trying to get a text box next to a delete button?  (sorry for language barrier here)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is:

```
testTypeNode.Text = testTypeNode.Text & "" & _
                                                            " <img src=""../images/delete_16x.ico""" & _
                                                            " style=""text-align:bottom; cursor:pointer;"" alt=""Delete TestType""" & _
                                                            " title=""Delete TestType"" onclick=""javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete? Any running tests will be aborted!'))" & _
                                                            " {" & ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnDeleteTestType, "" & sequenceNode.Value.ToString & _
                                                            WordSeparationChar & testTypeNode.Value.ToString & "") & ";};"" />" & _
                                                            " <input type = ""text"" id = ""txtExperimentalStressdays"" name =""ExperimentalStressdays"" size = ""5"" title=""Please enter the Experimental Stressdays"" onclick="javascript:IsNumeric()/>"
```

Comment: Moving forward with another question on above answer. How I set the visibility conditions for the above text box id = ""txtExperimentalStressdays"". Am expecting to hide the by using this conditions as if testdata = 'Yes' then txtExperimentalStressdays.visible = true else txtExperimentalStressdays.visible= false end if the above code is not allowing me to do this kind of task please help.

Comment: Second Question facing with the above code is: How can i validate the txtExperimentalStressdays data is numberic or not? Please help